# Add product option price to Cart page - Opencart?

Tags: opencart

How i can add options price to cart.tpl ???

i find option price in product.tpl

```
 <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
            - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small><br />
            <?php } ?>
```

Is there a way to add price to this code?

In the product.tpl and the product.php (controller) we have $option_value['price'] but I don't see this in the cart.php or the cart.tpl. How can we pull this variable into the cart and the checkout page to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cart.php search for this line

```php
$option_data[] = array(
    'name'  => $option['name'],
    'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
);
```

Around the line 226 and you can add the price like this

```php
$option_data[] = array(
    'name'  => $option['name'],
    'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),
    'price' => $this->currency->format($option['price'])
);
// var_dump($option); // look more options
```

Now in the cart.tpl you can show the price

```php
<?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
    - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?> 
    price: <?php echo $option['price']; ?></small><br />
<?php } ?>
```